# What is "with-eval-after-load" in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

I came across the macro `with-eval-after-load` when trying to install `persp-mode` from [here](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el). But I am unable to find the macro inside Emacs and/or on Google. Where is it defined? Is it part of standard Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From `etc/NEWS`:

```
* Lisp Changes in Emacs 24.4
...
** New macro `with-eval-after-load'.
This is like the old `eval-after-load', but better behaved.
```

Emacs 24.4 was released on 20th October 2014.

`eval-after-load` is considered ill-behaved because it is a function, not a macro, and thus requires the code inside it to be quoted, which means that it cannot be byte-compiled.  It also accepts only one form, so if you have more than one, you need to use `progn`.  For example:

```
(eval-after-load "foo"
  '(progn
     (setq foo 42)
     (setq bar 17)))
```

The equivalent version with `with-eval-after-load` would be:

```
(with-eval-after-load "foo"
  (setq foo 42)
  (setq bar 17))
```

---

As noted by [Clément](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695591/cl%c3%a9ment) in a comment, one disadvantage of `with-eval-after-load` is that you cannot rely on macros defined in the module in question, while with `eval-after-load` you can be sure that such macros are defined and available to use.  This was [discussed on emacs-devel](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-02/msg00714.html).

Comment: *FWIW:* If that's all that is meant by "better behaved" then I'd say that that is pretty much false advertising. I sincerely hope there is a better reason than what is given in the `NEWS` for bothering to add this macro to Emacs.

Comment: @Drew `with-eval-after-load` arranges for the body to be byte-compiled, whereas `eval-after-load` does not.  That was the main reason for its addition, iirc.

Comment: @lunaryorn: Ah, yes, that makes sense. (Though often the body is not something that benefits much from compiling. And byte-compiling does not necessarily make for "better behavior".) Another important difference is that (according to the paltry doc) the macro apparently evaluates `BODY` "***each time*** `LIBRARY` is loaded". (*Not* doing that is one of the aims of `eval-after-load`.)

Comment: @lunaryorn: I was wrong that evaluating `BODY` each time is a difference.  See Emacs [bug #16810](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16810).

Comment: On the other hand, the semantics of with-eval-after-load are subtly different: you can't (reliably) call a macro defined in package `foo` in a `with-eval-after-load 'foo` block.  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-02/msg00714.html

Comment: @Clément thank you for prying that info from Stefan. I would never have figured out how or why this was happening.